# New site going on to an old domain

Tags: seo, google-ranking, search-engine-bots

I have a client who over the years has managed to get their product to the top of Google for many different search terms.  They're adamant that the new site shouldn't have a detrimental effect to their google ranking.

The site will be replacing the site that is on there current domain, as well as going up on to 5 further domains.

Will any of this lose the client there current ranking on google?

Comment: Will the content of the site be the same?  If I'm not mistaken, SEO is largely about content.  If you were to change all of the content then I'd imagine it would have an effect.

Comment: Is the new site relevant to the same search terms the the old site got ranked for?

Answer (score 1):

Google re-ranks the sites it has regularly. If the site changes, the ranking very well could... if more or fewer people link to it or if the terms on the site (the content) is different.

The effect might be good or bad, but uploading different content isn't going to make their rank go away overnight or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Page Rank is most about incoming links. So if the incoming links won't be broken page rank will not be affected that much.
Though, overall ranking is not just Page Rank, so... further discussion is needed

Answer (score 0):

if they retain current link structure they should be fine